# Query-Annotation in Spring-Data Mongo to search for key/value of a Map

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have an entity containing a key/value-Map which I want to use with Spring-Data Mongo.
Persistence worked very easy. Now I want to implement a very dynamic Query on this map, where also the KEY of the query should be parameterized (or a part of it):

```
public interface EntityItemRepository extends MongoRepository<EntityItem, String>{

@Query("{values.?0:?1}")
public List<EntityItem> findByValues(String key,String value);

....
```

so that I could easily do a

```
findByValues('lastname','Schneider');
```

Here is my Entity:

```
public class EntityItem {

@Id
private String id;

private Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();

...
```

I debugged through StringBasedMongoQuery and found out, that only the value (so "?1") is getting bound, but not the key ("?0") of the Query. I made some changes to StringBasedMongoQuery and now it works... but I'm wondering if there is a better solution than hacking my own StringBasedMongoQuery :)

In org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery i changed (#262):

```
    for (String field : dbo.keySet()) {
        collectParameterReferencesIntoBindings(bindings, dbo.get(field));
    }
```

to

```
    for (String field : dbo.keySet()) {
        collectParameterReferencesIntoBindings(bindings, field);
        collectParameterReferencesIntoBindings(bindings, dbo.get(field));
    }
```

and added some nasty quote-string replacements... as I said now it works, but this all doesn't feel right.

I hope this is no duplicate, I searched for hours and couldn't find any issue on this.

Comment: Too bad there was no answer :(